# login screen, navigation and UI Tab Bar Controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.2

I am asking a general question about UI tab bar controller. In my app there is a login screen and on succesful login a tab bar based interface needs to be displayed. So I have navigation controller as the root controller and I am pushing a tab bar controller onto the navigation stack after succesful login. It is working fine for me. Tabs are coming and switching is also working. Just that content view controller's title that is displayed on the navigation bar is not coming. When I add content view controller directly to the navigation stack it comes but when my content view controller is inside tab bar the title doesnt come. Also I hav read on many websites that tab bar controller should not be added as a child of any other controller. It should always be the root controller of the window. Then what I am doing is not the right usage? How do I go about it? I cant make tab bar controller as the root controller in app delegate because there is a login screen and navigation requirement. Please guide me. I do know that similar questions have been posted before but I was not able to understand this clearly.

Comment: This is really hard to read. Follow http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 and you'll be fine though.